# CEP não sendo lido com máscara

Tags: javascript, html, html5, cep, input-mask

Tenho um formulário onde preciso do CEP e com isso preencho todos os dados como rua, bairro, cidade, etc. Recentemente fiz uma adição ao HTML com máscaras para facilitar o input de dados, mas ao falê-lo não consigo mais puxar os dados com essas máscaras no meio dos números.

```
// Nessa chamada o cep já vem como 00.000-000
$("#cep").focusout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+$(this).val()+'/json/unicode/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resposta){
            $("#rua").val(resposta.logradouro);
            $("#bairro").val(resposta.bairro);
            $("#cidade").val(resposta.localidade);
            $("#estado").val(resposta.uf);
            $("#estado").css('opacity', '1').change();
            document.getElementById("numero").focus();
            estado = resposta.uf;
        }
    });
});
```

Não sei se é possível fazer a pesquisa com a máscara ou preciso tirar. Na dúvida tentei limpar com os comandos abaixo mas não funcionou.

```
$(this).val.toString().replace(/-/, '').replace(/./, '')
$(this).val.toString().replace('-', '').replace('.', '')
```

Está retornando esse erro (retirado do console do chrome):

```
cadastro.php:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/08.588-310/json/unicode/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

jquery.min.js:4 GET https://viacep.com.br/ws/08.588-310/json/unicode/ net::ERR_FAILED 400
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Isso parece ser mais um problema de CORS do que de validação de informação.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Mudei o replace para:

```
$(this).val().toString().replace(/-/, '').replace('.', '')
```

e funcionou.

```
cep antes 00.000-000

cep agora 00000000
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Veja a mensagem de erro: `'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score -3):

O erro acontece porque a url está indo com a mascará do CPF (00.000-000). Para remover, pode usar regex com o replace.

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

O regex "/[^\d]/g" irá remover tudo que não for números da string.

Comment: Veja a mensagem de erro: `'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`